# Mixed (anisotropic) Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Consider real variables $x, y$ and a function $f(x, y) \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^2)$, say for some $s \in (0, 1)$. I am trying to get an understanding of mixed Sobolev spaces of the form $H^s_x(H^s_y)$, where the mixed Sobolev norm is defined by
$$ \Vert f\Vert_{H^s_x(H^s_y)} = \Vert \Vert f\Vert_{H^s_y}\Vert_{H^s_x}.$$ 
In other words, $H^s_x$ functions taking values in $H^s_y$. My question is, does $f \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^2)$ automatically imply $f \in H^s_x(H^s_y)$?

It is obvious that $L^2_x(L^2_y) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, but in the case of Sobolev spaces, it is not so clear. Understanding this (relatively simple ?) case will help me understand the general theory better.

Edit: From Lions and Magenes, and also from Michael Renardy's answer below, I think that the correct thing to try to infer is $f \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^2) \Rightarrow f \in H^s_x(L^2_y)$. But it is not clear to me how to prove this.

Comment: These are called anisotropic Sobolev spaces.  You can find a nice presentation in   Chapter 4 (vol 2) of Lions & Magenes book.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks for the comment. I am looking up Lions and Magenes and have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. If a function $f$ is in $H^1(R^2)$, it means that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are in $L^2$, but if $f$ is in $H^1(H^1)$, it means that $f_{xy}$ is in $L^2$.

Comment: I looked at Lions and Magenes, and I think that the correct inference should be $f \in H^s_x(L^2_y)$. Is this correct? I am running into trouble trying to prove this directly from the definition. Could you please give me a hint how to prove this?

Comment: The correct inference is that $f\in H^s(L^2)\cap L^2(H^s)$. You should look at the equivalent statement for Fourier transforms.

Comment: I think: $f \in H^s_x(L^2_y) \Leftrightarrow \Vert (1 + \xi^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}^x(\xi)\Vert_{L^2_y} \in L^2_\xi$, where $\hat{f}^x$ means Fourier transform with respect to the variable $x$ only. This holds iff $\Vert \Vert (1 + \xi^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}^x(\xi)\Vert_{L^2_y} \Vert_{L^2_\xi} < \infty$, which would follow from $f \in H^s$. I would really appreciate your opinion on whether I understand this correctly.

Comment: The other inference $f \in L^2_x(H^s_y)$ would also follow similarly.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I read somewhere that the correct interpretation might be $f \in H^{s/2}_x(H^{s/2}_y)$ by interpolation. If this is right, could you point to a reference? Is this interpolation result in Lions and Magenes?